# Swift: Finding views in a superview (without a for loop)

Tags: swift

I'm using the following code to find a certain subview inside my view. It works fine, and the `for` loop runs only once because it only finds one subview that satisfies the `where` clause.

```
for view in boardView.subviews where (view as? PlayingCardView)?.position.location == source.
    && (view as! PlayingCardView).position.column == source.column
    && (view as! PlayingCardView).position.row >= source.row
```

However, it seems weird that I'm running a loop here when I'm not actually doing any...loop-y things (know what I mean)?

Is there some other way to "search" like this? Like a way to use `subviews.index(of:)` and use the conditions from the `where` clause, or something like that?

---

Also, I know that I could do the same code like this:

```
for view in boardView.subviews {
   if let cardView = view as? PlayingCardView {
      if cardView.position.location == source.location
        && (view as! PlayingCardView).position.column == source.column
        && (view as! PlayingCardView).position.row >= source.row {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Is one of these ways computationally faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the `filter` method.

```
if let card = (boardView.subviews as? [PlayingCardView])?.filter({
    return $0.position.location == source.location
        && $0.position.column == source.column
        && $0.position.row >= source.row
}).first {
    // Do stuff
    print(card)
}
```

Or if you want to find the first card that satisfies your arguments, you can use the `first` method.

```
if let card = (boardView.subviews as? [PlayingCardView])?.first(where: {
    return $0.position.location == source.location
        && $0.position.column == source.column
        && $0.position.row >= source.row
}) {
    // Do stuff
    print(card)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this sounds pretty perfect!

Comment: Well it seems perfect... however I'm getting an error:

Answer (score 0):

`first(where: )` will give you the first element in the array that satisfies a condition (assuming that you only want to do it on one element since it's not "loopy"):

```
let view = boardView.subviews.first {
    guard let cardView = $0 as? PlayingCardView else { return false }
    return cardView.position.location == source.location
            && cardView.position.column == source.column
            && cardView.position.row >= source.row
}

// do stuffs to `view`
```

It will stop as soon as a match is found so that's about as efficient as you can get. In reality though, it hardly matters as you tend to have only a small number of subviews. Otherwise the GPU will give out first from having to render all of them.